# Java swing timer break

Tags: java, swing, timer

Is there any way to do this? This is for a simulator I'm making. I want it so that when the counter(numTimes) reaches 139, it stops the timer. I tried delcaring but no initializing the timer before the Action Listener and stopping the timer within the actionPerformed function, but it gave me an error. I don't want to use another method(but if it works better then I'm all for it), and the while loop at the bottom causes the program to freeze? How can I make this work?

```
ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    numTimes++;
                    switch(m1values[numTimes])
                    {
                        case 1:
                            new Moves().L();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            new Moves().Lprime();
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            new Moves().R();
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            new Moves().Rprime();
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            new Moves().F();
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            new Moves().Fprime();
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            new Moves().B();
                            break;
                        case 8:
                            new Moves().Bprime();
                            break;
                        case 9:
                            new Moves().U();
                            break;
                        case 10:
                            new Moves().Uprime();
                            break;
                        case 11:
                            new Moves().D();
                            break;
                        case 12:
                            new Moves().Dprime();
                            break;
                        default:    
                    }
                    drawAndButtons.add(new graphics());
                    cubeSpace.repaint();
                    if(numTimes >= 139)
                    {
                        numTimes = 0;
                        m1going = false;
                    }
                }
            };
            Timer timer = new Timer( 500 , taskPerformer);
            timer.setRepeats(true);
            timer.start();
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            m1going = true;
            while(m1going = true)
            {}
            timer.stop();
```

Comment: The while loop will never stop, because you typed `=` instead of `==`. This is normally not a problem, but this is a very, very special case, when what you have is a boolean.

Comment: i changed it and it still freezes

Comment: Why not stop the timer with in the ActionListener?

Comment: i tried, but i got an error

Answer (score 2):

This is a 1-character typo. The while loop will never stop, because you typed `=` instead of `==`. The reason this even compiles at all is because the expression `m1going = true` returns the value of `true` as well as assigning `true` to `m1going`. The while loop requires a boolean, and that's what it gets.

This is a common error in C/C++, because an `int` is a valid boolean. Normally, Java will catch this for you, and complain that you can't put an `int` (or whatever) in a while loop, but if you make this mistake with a `boolean`, it is not caught.

Comment: oh wow, i guess that's something you miss after programming for 8 hours. Thanks.

Comment: @user3142972 How do you plan on exiting your `while(true) {}` with no code to exit the loop?

Comment: in the action listener function, if numTimes reaches 139 it changes the boolean, and the while true statement is based on that boolean, so when it's changed, it should exit

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the while loop is if it's executed within the context of EDT, it will stop the timer from been triggered

Instead, get rid of loop and stop the `Timer` within the `ActionListener`

```
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                numTimes++;
                //...
                if(numTimes >= 139)
                {
                    numTimes = 0;
                    ((Timer)evt.getSource()).stop();
```